# RHEL + how to verify the dmesg log in order to find the root cause of unexpected reboot

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, dmesg

we have RHEL 7.6 server ( VM server )

that performed unexpected reboot twice ( we can see the reboot from last command )

after review on dmesg output , we can see the following messages  ,

```
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata12: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata11: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata10: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata14: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata13: SATA lin

k down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata15: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata16: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata20: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata21: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata26: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata19: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata29: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata32: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata28: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata31: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata25: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata30: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata22: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata18: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata17: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata23: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata24: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  3 09:56:42 server_MA02 kernel: ata27: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
```

is that above messages chould be part of the problem that VM machines perform unexpected reboot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "VM server", do you mean the server is a physical machine that hosts VMs, or that the server is a Virtual Machine?

If the logs are from a physical machine, it seems a large number of SATA links have died at once; maybe power supply problems, or SATA controller problems?

If the server is a VM, this might mean the host suddenly stopped providing virtual disks to the VM: you should check the logs of the physical host (or contact its administrators, if it's hosted by someone else) to see if the host has a hardware problem of some sort.

Comment: its real  Virtual Machine not physical